# mask two UIImages by using cgImage.mask not working, but works for imageview.layer.mask

Tags: ios, calayer, cgimage

I have two images, which both have alpha channel. I want to comine them together. It do works for UIImageView, but I want to do it by using cgimage,  which without creat a UIImageView.
I tried cgimage like this is not working:

```
    func  combine3(_ bg: UIImage, cover: UIImage) -> UIImage?{
        let size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        
        let maskRef = cover.cgImage!
        let mask = CGImage.init(maskWidth: maskRef.width, height: maskRef.height, bitsPerComponent: maskRef.bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel: maskRef.bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow: maskRef.bytesPerRow, provider: maskRef.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: false)
        let masked = bg.cgImage?.masking(mask!)
        let outPutImage = UIImage(cgImage: masked!)
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return outPutImage
    }
```

but for UIImageView, it works pretty good:

```
        let bg = creatBGImageFinal()!
        bgIV.image = bg

        let cover = createCoverImageFinal(progress: 0)!
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.contents = cover.cgImage
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        maskIV.layer.mask = layer
```

bg:
[image]
cover,which is a picture with an white circle in the middle, the others is Transparent:
[image]
result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, reverse the mask: 
[image]

The rule for cgImage masking is `Dst = 1 - Src`.

Then draw the masked image onto image context with opacity:

```swift
func combine3(_ bg: UIImage, cover: UIImage, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 1)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    let maskRef = cover.cgImage!
    let mask = CGImage.init(maskWidth: maskRef.width, height: maskRef.height, bitsPerComponent: maskRef.bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel: maskRef.bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow: maskRef.bytesPerRow, provider: maskRef.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: false)!
    let masked = bg.cgImage!.masking(mask)!
    // adjust for lower-left-origin CG coordinates
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
    context.draw(masked, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

Result:

[image]